# I'm following a tutorial for GODOT for a platformer game. Everything was going great until I started coding death and respawn

Tags: godot, gdscript

I've narrowed down the issue to the register player function. If I block that out the game runs fine. But if I don't it crashes and gives me the following error:

**Invalid type in function 'connect' in base 'KinematicBody2D (Player.gd)'. Cannot convert argument 4 from int to Array.**

I'm assuming this means that there is an issue in my player script but I'm not sure what it could be. I'm confused.

```
extends Node

var playerScene = preload("res://Scenes/Player.tscn")
var spawnPosition = Vector2.ZERO
var currentPlayerNode = null

func _ready():
    spawnPosition = $Player.global_position
    #register_player($Player)

func register_player(player):
        currentPlayerNode = player
        currentPlayerNode.connect("died", self, "on_player_died", CONNECT_DEFERRED)
        
func create_player():
    var playerInstance = playerScene.instance()
    add_child_below_node(currentPlayerNode, playerInstance)
    register_player(playerInstance)
    

func on_player_died():
    currentPlayerNode.queue_free()
    create_player()
```

I've tried looking at the player script but couldn't figure out what the issue was. Again, it is only when I try to call that particular function.

Comment: the connect method is looking for an array and you are passing it an int.  can you post the definition of the connect method?

I can't find anything in the docs about a fourth parameter... What are you trying to do with CONNECT_DEFERRED?

Answer (score 0):

This answer assumes you are using Godot 3.5, the current stable version at the time of writing.

The `connect` function takes up to five arguments - the fourth is an array of arguments to be passed to the callback, not the flags:

```
Error connect ( String signal, Object target, String method, Array binds=[ ], int flags=0 )
```

[docs source](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_object.html#class-object-method-connect)

You need to pass an empty array if you don't want to pass any arguments but want to set flags

```
currentPlayerNode.connect("died", self, "on_player_died", [], CONNECT_DEFERRED)
```

Comment: Yes, that is the version I'm using.

This made it not crash but now I've lost functionality in the game. My player cannot move at all. Interesting.